# B Tree Bulk Loading differs to creation

Tags: algorithms

Reading this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) on B Trees, I have implemented the algorithm.

I got to the section on `Initial construction` and ran my algorithm implementation and it differed. With 8 being the root index.

Am I right in thinking, that when you bulk load your leafs are going to full, but when you add the indexes individually the leafs are going to be half empty?

Or have I got my, maximum indexes numbers and maximum children numbers the wrong way round. In my implementation I split the indexes when they reach a size of 4.

Comment: (Both depend on the goals set in the implementation but, yes, with bulk loading there is more up-front information to exploit, the result is "optimal" (it may anticipate further insertions). "Half empty" is an extreme case, expect somewhere between lower limit and full with "random insertion".)

Comment: @greybeard so when you do deletion, you can rely on the fact you can rejoin nodes due to that property of having half full nodes. Could you get into that state if you do the initial construction? Or do you need other strategies? Do you know any other good places to read up on the indexing algorithms

Comment: (This is not [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=cs.stackexchange.com).) `[doing deletion, one] can rely on the fact [that one] can rejoin nodes due to that property of having half full nodes.` I'm afraid I don't get what you are getting at - nodes allowed to get "half empty", I can join half-empty siblings to form a full node. During construction/repeated insertion, it may become necessary to create one more node. If I take keys just from one (overflowing) node, that is a *split* resulting in half-filled nodes. My reference texts are old - take a look at PD collection sources.